# Yii2 register JS in controller

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

is it possible to register Javascript in a controller action in Yii2?

More or less I think:

```
class MyController extends yii\web\Controller {
    public function actionView(){
        //Is it possible to register Javascript here?

        return $this->render('view');
    }
}
```

Comment: In yii 1.x you could register the script through clientScript component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your controller gives you access to its view, which in turn allows you to render JS.

```
$this->getView()->registerJs("yourJsGoesHere");
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#getView()-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail